# Katex rendering equations multiple times

Tags: markdown, static-site, docusaurus, katex

I am using Docusaurus to generate a static website. I integrated katex using the official instructions (https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/math-equations).

I want to render this:

```latex
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \begin{split}    
        u &= u^0(x,y)+z\varphi(x,y)  \\
        v &= v^0(x,y)+z\theta(x,y) \\
        w &= w^0(x,y)
    \end{split}
    \tag{1.1}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

What I get is this:
[image: katex output]

What I do not understand is, that the text is rendered again underneath the correctly rendered equation. What am I missing?

Comment: I use your snippets and get the right result. Can you please post your configuration ? Did you forget the css file ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

The problem was that I didn't exactly follow the [instructions in the docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/math-equations#self-hosting-katex-assets).

After I downloaded all the assets from GitHub and unzipped them into the `/static` folder, everything worked fine.